# i have install prisma but there is no specification of prisma in package.json

Tags: json, prisma

i have install prisma using 
npm install -g prisma

but in my packaje.JSON file there is no such prisma configuration available ..what shoulkd i do?

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "mysql-node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "demo",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node db.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "apollo-server": "^2.5.0",
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.5.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel-preset-node5": "^12.0.1",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "graphql": "^14.3.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^4.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "mysql": "^2.17.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.1.1",
    "sequelize": "^5.8.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: It is installed globally so it isn't needed as a local dependency.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** run `npm install prisma` without the `-g`.

---

**Explanations:**

The command "`npm install -g prisma`" installs Prisma **globally** on your computer. This is useful so that you can run commands like `prisma deploy` directly in your terminal.

Installing Prisma as a dependency of your project (in package.json), will allow anyone cloning your project and running `npm install` to also download Prisma. However, you won't be able to access the command `prisma deploy` directly in your terminal, and you will need to put it in a script in package.json.

Eg:

```
{
...
  scripts: {
    "deploy": "prisma deploy"
  }
...
}
```

And then `npm run deploy`

To install Prisma locally, simply run `npm install prisma` without the `-g`